# Simulator crashed when I run an app on it (OS X 10.8.4)

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

There is no error in my code andd the log is :

```
Myapp(1570) malloc: recording malloc stacks to disk using standard recorder
Myapp(1570) malloc: stack logs being written into /tmp/stack-logs.1570.Myapp.4zOLQO.index
```

How can I fix this? Thank you very much!

Edit: I change Debugger to GDB, and it is OK ,but LLDB will crashed.

Comment: getting some compile time warning?

Comment: @Ishank Nope. This drive me crazy...

Comment: have u tested on a real device?

Comment: @Ishank It's all right this morning, and I install [Reveal] (http://revealapp.com) and update to OS X 10.8.4, then this happened...

Comment: @Ishank And my app is running OK in my iPhone5

Comment: @Ishank My workmate update OS X to 10.8.4 and the same thing happened...

Comment: may be, u can try deleting and re-installing the App..

Answer (score 2):

Apple have found the issue. What we can do is just waiting for some update...

[image]